# web scraper script error problems

Tags: android, python

i am just new at coding with python only been doing it for two months and a little bit. i am coding on my android device with qpython. I do coding for fun and i will be doing it for profit later on.

I studied a ebook which had some web scraper code in it. I am currently fiddling with a copy of this code and have run into this error: Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts/.last_tmp.py", line 25,
in <module> Scraper(news).scrape() 
File"/storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts/.last_tmp.py", line 14, 
in _init_ html = r.read() NameError: global name 'r' is not defined. 1|u0_a162@g3:/ $
```

I think it might be as simple as asigning a local variable within the scrape()  am not sure though. Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
class Scraper: 
    def __init__( self, site): 
        self.site = site 


        def scrape( self): r = urllib.request\
         .urlopen("http://news.google.com/") 
        html = r.read() 
        parser = "html.parser" 
        sp = BeautifulSoup( html, parser) 
        for tag in sp.find_all("a"): 
            url = tag.get("href") 
            if url is None: continue 
            if "html" in url: 
                print("\n" + url) 


news = " https:// news.google.com/" 
Scraper(news).scrape()
```

I just would like to know what it is I need to do to get this script up and running and why i need to to do these things. I have python 3 on my laptop and run this script from there as well as my android phone.

Comment: What happens if you change  `.urlopen("http://news.google.com/")`  to `.urlopen(site)`  or `.urlopen("https:// news.google.com/")`

Comment: Also, maybe `news = " https:// news.google.com/"` needs to be `news = "https:// news.google.com/"`

Comment: I just ran the code on my phone. i got a syntax error for the colon at https: this is for .urlopen("http://news.google.com/"). i will try the others and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: yes, missed that. 1" https:// news.google.com/"` should be `"https://news.google.com/"` Not there is a whitespace before https and a whitespace before news in your code.

Comment: I tried those things and still got the same errors as above. as i understand it the IDLE marks the mistake from where it noticed it. then you have to look at the previous line of code just before the error was noticed. i did that and did all the things you said above and still got the same errors. On another note i can download and extract the files to the site packages file.

Comment: On another note i can download and extract the files to the site packages file for beautifulsoup because i am getting an error for importing it on my computer. So i checked the python files on my computer (I uninstalled python 2.7.13.) i had installed Python 3.6.2rc2 on my computer and i don't have any Python 3.6.2rc2 files but a couple of python 2.7.13 files left over. why is that?

Comment: I think i just solved this problem. It seems that the urllib.urlopen has been removed from the urllib's functions. I can't 100% confirm this but it kind of makes sense in that without a certain function present in the library it would throw out an exception.  Thanks Alexander Higgins for your input on this problem.  You got me focused on the right problem which was the previous line of code before the NameError. Now the question remains how do i open the url to scrape the information from the website? Oh fun, fun. This is why i love programming!